# .htaccess problems, impossible for me to remove .php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want your help.
I have this url: **wwww.myurl.com/?verfy=CDPOR888** OR **wwww.myurl.com/index.php?verfy=CDPOR888**

I would like to be like this: **wwww.myurl.com/CDPOR888**

**Please help, how can i do it with .htaccess?**

I tried this code in .htaccess but not working:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /?perms_verify=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

but the problem is .php, when i remove it i get an error.

**NOTE: .htaccess with case insensitive**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just use this rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# request is not for a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# request is not for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# rewrite to destination path
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ ?verfy=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please replace this rule!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Use this rule
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: This will just rewrite `/CDPOR888` to `/CDPOR888.php` and that will cause a 404 since `CDPOR888.php` doesn't exist.

Comment: did you tried "RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
//Use this rule
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]"

Comment: Interesting, I got 404 as expected because `CDPOR888.php` doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you upload your .htaccess file?

Comment: That has same 3 lines as in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your .htaccess file as

```html
DirectoryIndex index.php

# remove the next 3 lines if you see a 500 server error


FileETag none
ServerSignature Off

Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]{1,16})$ index.php?verify=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

On wwww.myurl.com/index.php page , write the logic to catch verify value using **GET**  method and do your further operations